# How to convert a pdf into colour?

Tags: pdf, printing, colors

I have got a pdf file (text and images) containing pages with colours and pages in black and white (b&w). The file shall be printed, double sided and preserving the colours. Now I am not really printing the document from a computer but uploading it to a repository (UBP), and then at the machine (Jansen) I am choosing a file from the repository to be printed. 
The machine tells me "x pages colour, y pages b&w" and splitts the document accordingly without giving me the option to print it as one document. It is printing e.g. page 1,2,3 (colour), blank backside, 4,5,6 (b&w), 
blank backside, 7,8,9 (colour), blank backside, 10 (b&w).
I would like to get pages 1 to 10 double-sided, of course. If it was single-sided printing there would be no problem. Thus I need to convert the document into an "all pages coloured" document, i.e. the pages should be marked as coloured, maybe by changing black to a combination of colours which give black, similar to what ink jet printers do. I used "print to pdf" on my PC, printing the initial PDF document into another PDF, while selecting colored printing in the print options dialog. Despite the fact that the document itself is colored, the "printer" is able to tell which pages are coloured and which ones are b&w.
I do not have the source for the pdf, thus I cannot recompile or something like that. The machine is an in-house machine and it is not telling me what OS it is running behind the custom surface of its touch pad. (Same question as: which OS is your coffee machine using?)

---

After adding yellow dots to all pages, all pages are detected as coloured, but the machine still issues blank pages in between - but between other pages then before! Tested with another all-colour document: same problem. Thus: The problem of additional blank pages in between (always a backside) is not about colour/b&w, but the copy machine has got an issue.

Comment: If you're printing in colour then the printer should have no problems printing a colour page on the other side of a B&W page. What printer is it, and used on which OS? "Colouring the PDF" makes no sense since we have no clue what the contents are. Are they images (including text as images)? Actual text you can select? A combination of both?

Comment: Sorry, I realise that English is not your first language but it is really hard to make out what the problem is. Are you saying that when you have 1 colour page on a front side then 1 b&w page on the back that the colour page prints in b&w? If so, this is a print driver error, do you have the latest driver installed?

Comment: So clearly a problem with either this in-house "machine" or in-house OS (really? OS built from scratch in-house?) and not the PDFs themselves. I don't know on what basis you want the text and images to be coloured. What colours should be used? Just think about it a little...

Comment: Oh boy! I think you are stuffed then since you have no way of doing what you want. You would have to change the original so that it didn't happen.

Comment: "but the pages in the pdf marked as coloured" - There is no such PDF setting AFAIK. It depends on your printer driver whether you select to print a document in colour or B&W. In your case if you can't fix the "machine" then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to istall some kind of [PDF priter](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+printer) on your computer and print your initial PDF document into another PDF, while selecting colored printing in the print options dialog?

If, despite the fact that the document itself is colored, your *machine* is able to tell which pages are b&w, I suggest you use a PDF editor to add a yellow dot on every page. Those won't be visible, and besides, you should have [plenty of them already](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_steganography).

Comment: - Print to colour pdf: already tried, machine detects b&w on its own.

- Yellow dots (_more_ yellow dots): added, will test print tomorrow.

Comment: Yellow dots: all pages are detected as colour, but the Jansen-1 still issues blank pages in between - but between other pages then before. Tested with another all-colour document: same problem. Thus: It isn't about colour/b&w, but the Jansen-1 has got an issue. Time to contact the support and close the question as too localised. While your answer did not solve my problem, it answered my question and help me to narrow down my problem, thus: accepted! (I would also upvote but I'm missing the necessary reputation yet.)